# Organizing Python classes in modules and/or packages

Tags: python, class, module, package

I like the Java convention of having one public class per file, even if there are sometimes good reasons to put more than one public class into a single file. In my case I have alternative implementations of the same interface. But if I would place them into separate files, I'd have redundant names in the import statements (or misleading module names):

```
import someConverter.SomeConverter
```

whereas `someConverter` would be the file (and module) name and `SomeConverter` the class name. This looks pretty inelegant to me. To put all alternative classes into one file would lead to a more meaningful import statement:

```
import converters.SomeConverter
```

But I fear that the files become pretty large, if I put all related classes into a single module file. What is the Python best practise here? Is one class per file unusual?

Comment: By the time you're dealing with a project consisting of 10'000 classes, you'll be happy if you can find a (public) class by its file (and package) name instead of having to search  the contents of all files.. that's probably the rationale why Java enforces that there is only one public class per file and that the file name must be the class name.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A lot of it is personal preference. Using python modules, you do have the option to keep each class in a separate file and still allow for `import converters.SomeConverter` (or `from converters import SomeConverter`)

Your file structure could look something like this:

```
* converters
     - __init__.py
     - baseconverter.py
     - someconverter.py
     - otherconverter.py
```

and then in your `__init__.py` file:

```
from baseconverter import BaseConverter
from otherconverter import OtherConverter
```

Answer (score 51):

Zach's solution breaks on Python 3. Here is a fixed solution.

A lot of it is personal preference. Using python modules, you do have the option to keep each class in a separate file and still allow for `import converters.SomeConverter` (or `from converters import SomeConverter`)

Your file structure could look something like this:

```
* converters
     - __init__.py
     - baseconverter.py
     - someconverter.py
     - otherconverter.py
```

and then in your `__init__.py` file:

```
from converters.baseconverter import BaseConverter
from converters.otherconverter import OtherConverter
```

Comment: How about just "from .baseconverter import BaseConverter" ?

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, I've been out of touch with python in recent times, if someone can verify Michael's solution above then please feel free to edit my answer and add that as alternative. (Don't change my original because I think it's a matter of preference as to which one looks more readable so let's give the users both the options)

Comment: Michael's answer does work, but PEP 8 discourages relative imports.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module

Comment: @JasonPearson Not anymore, explicit relative imports are fine for intra-package imports: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-October/104476.html

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions are good, but the problem with importing modules in `__init__.py` is that this will cause **all the modules to be loaded twice(inefficient)**. Try adding a print statement at the end of `otherconverter.py` and run `otherconverter.py`. (You'll see that the print statement is executed twice)

I prefer the following. Use another package with name "_converter" and define everything there. And then your "converters.py" becomes the interface for accessing all public members

```
* _converters
     - __init__.py
     - baseconverter.py
     - someconverter.py
     - otherconverter.py

*  converters.py
```

where `converters.py` is

```
from _converters.someconverter import SomeConverter
from _converters.otherconverter import OtherConverter
...
...
...
converters = [SomeConverter, OtherConverter, ...]
```

And as the previous solutions mentioned, it is a personal choice. A few practices involve defining a module "interace.py" within the package and importing all public members here. If you have many modules to load, you should choose efficiency over aesthetics.