# performance of modules in Python

Tags: python, performance

Which is the best: create the modules and put them in a separate file and import them or put them all together in the same file?

Is there any  significant difference?

Comment: module == file.  I can't parse the question.  A module **is** a "separate file".  How can you put modules (which are files) into "the same file"?

Comment: @S.Lott: My best guess is that he is looking if he should write every thing in one file or decompose it in modules. The same discussion as .py and .pyc ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many Python classes should I put in one file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106896/how-many-python-classes-should-i-put-in-one-file)

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+class+module

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organizing Python classes in modules and/or packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842616/organizing-python-classes-in-modules-and-or-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as disscussion on .py and .pyc. Having modules allows you to **load them faster** through precompiled modules. How ever negligible, this adds to performance. Though **execution speed remains the same**.

Please look at the following for a detailed answer. Repeating it is not useful.

- [What is the difference between .py and .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918689/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-pyc-files)
- [Why are main runnable Python scripts not compiled to pyc files like modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878479/python-pyc-files-main-file-not-compiled)

[Edit:]

Decomposing the solution in modules is always better for future maintenance and enhances readability. The performance is almost always not the primary reason for decomposition of solution into various modules.