# How to properly import my module file into my test file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following file structure:

```
C:.
├───jobs_struct
│   │
│   └───app
│       └───job_struct
│           │   delta.py
│
└───test
    ├───integration
    └───unitaire
        │   test_delta.py
```

`test_delta.py` is a pytest file and import `delta.py` to test its functions.

In `test_delta.py`, I do not understand how I am supposed to import `delta.py`. I have tried the following:

### Attempt 1

```
sys.path.append("../../")
from jobs_struct.app.job_struct.delta import ApplyDelta
```

Throws:

> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jobs_struct'

### Attempt 2

```
from jobs_struct.app.job_struct.delta import ApplyDelta
```

> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jobs_struct'

### Attempt 3

```
sys.path.append("/jobs_struct/app/job_struct")
from delta import ApplyDelta
```

> from delta import ApplyDelta

> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta'

### Additionnal details

Some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827160/importing-correctly-with-pytest) recommend to include **init**.py files at specific locations (or everywhere). I would like to avoid changing/adding anything to the app itself.

Moreover, the pytest command is ran from the root of the project (if that has any impact).

### Question

How to correctly import my module, knowing that using absolute path **is not** an option, in order to be able to run my test file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sys.path.append('your_complete_path_to/job_struct')`

and then: `from delta import ApplyDelta` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. See attempt 3 in the question :(