# Proper style of coding __init__.py in Python modules

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint, spyder

I'm not that fluent in Python so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is common practice or the proper way to do it.

I'm creating a module `archive` contaning files with one class each, e.g. `SmsArchiveReader.py` with class `SmsArchiveReader` inside. To make the imports less tedious, I decided to import the classes directly into the `__init__.py`.

However, both Spyder and Pylint have issues with my `__init__.py`, with Spyder telling me that I shouldn't have unused imports, and Pylint telling me that I shouldn't use absolute imports. Both suggestions seem pointless to me, since this is `__init__.py` we're talking about, but I'm open to suggestions.

Image below:[image: Spyder reaction]

As for the look I wanted to achieve, I wanted the code using this module to look like that:

```
import archive

myReader = archive.SmsArchiveReader()
myReader2 = archive.FooArchiveReader()
```

instead of:

```
import archive

myReader = archive.SmsArchiveReader.SmsArchiveReader()
myReader2 = archive.FooArchiveReader.FooArchiveReader()
```

So what's the correct practice of creating modules?

Comment: Spyder is wrong - `__init__.py` files *generally* have unused imports. I agree with Pylint though, I would use `from .SmsArchiveReader import SmsArchiveReader`.

Comment: Wow - I didn't even know ``from .foo import bar`` was a thing. I'll use that and stop disabling the pylint warning, thanks!

Comment: No problem. It is a little controversial, though; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4209641/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jonrsharpe said, it's a problem with Spyder IDE. This issue has been submitted to their bug tracker, the interested can follow its status on [Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2211).