# Issue with importing apps in Python / Django

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue while importing 'registration' app into any of my python scripts (PyCharm showing an error - "Unresolved reference 'registration'"). `Django-registration-redux` has been installed and loads fine e.g. from `urls.py`. I also have an issue with my own apps, which I never had an issue with. In the following `urls.py` `user_profile` is also not recognized. How do you go a folder level up rather than down, I know that if you are going into folders you include a dot for every folder, **but how do you go back?** This is probably not relevant for this case but in general. This is my project layout:

```
|--'project'
|   |--'Lib'
|   |   |--'site-packages'
|   |   |   |--'registration'
|   |--'src'
|   |   |--'proj'
|   |   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   |--'user_profile'
|   |   |   |-- forms.py
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
import user_profile.views as views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from django import forms

class UserProfileRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    field = forms.CharField()
```

**settings.py**

```
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

        INS

TALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',  # manually added
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # third party apps
        'crispy_forms',
        'debug_toolbar',
        # my apps
        'user_profile',
        'registration',
    ]
```

Comment: Yes I'm using virtualenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyCharm, go to `File -> Settings`. In the tabs on the left, choose `Project: <your_project_name> -> Project Interpreter` and choose the path to your virtualenv. That should get PyCharm to recognize the packages installed in your virtualenv.

As for the problem with your own apps, [there is a nice thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module) about the pros and cons of relative and absolute imports.

Comment: great thanks, it was PyCharm settings I had to tweak all along!

Answer (score 2):

You don't "go back", because you're not "in" anywhere to go back from.

Python uses the PYTHONPATH environment variable to determine where to import things from. A virtualenv will automatically put its root and the site-packages directory into that variable. If your virtualenv is the "project" directory, you probably need to do `from src.user_profile import views`.

Comment: It looks I'm getting there - `from project.src.user_profile import views`. So `user_profile` is resolved. But I can't use the same approach to reference to `registration`. Python doesn't seem to like `site-packages`, maybe it's just a dash sign? How can I access these apps without extra reference, can I change `settings.py` so that I can simply say `from user_profile import views` and `import registration`. Sorry for a long comment!

Comment: As I said, site-packages is on your python path already, so you just need to do `from registration import...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called 'relative imports'. Say you need to access your settings from your forms.py, you can do this

```
import from ..settings import YOUR_SETTING
```

Hope this helps!