# How to properly do importing during development of a python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

The file structure of the code I am working with right now is as follows:

```
school_project/
     __init__.py       #(empty)
     main_functions/
         __init__.py   #(empty)
         render.py
         filter.py
     helper_functions/
         __init__.py   #(empty)
         string.py
         utility.py
```

Currently, I need to use functions founded in `utility.py` in the file `render.py`. My first attempt at solving this problem was to do `import ..helper_functions.utility` in the file `render.py`.

Unfortunately, it was met with the following error message.

```
import ..helper_functions.utility
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

First off, I have no idea why this relative import is not working.

Secondly, should I just use an absolute import instead? In the form `import school_project.helper_functions.utility`? If so, would I then need to add the directory that `school_project/` is currently in to **PYTHONPATH**? How would I do this?

Would I just modify my computer's **PATH** and **PYTHONPATH** will adapt accordingly? Or are they separate entities and the process is a bit more involved? Ive looked at other threads but they all seem to modify **PYTHONPATH** at run time in the python script itself, something I see as a giant potential origin of bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you should do it:

```
  from ..helper_functions import utility
```

This will not work if you run your python program normally due to relative imports.

This is the way you are supposed to run it:

```
python3 -m helper_functions.utility
```

But it's somewhat verbose, and doesn't mix well with a shebang line like #!/usr/bin/env python3.

Although it's not unique. Your package structure is more complex. You'll need to **include the directory containing your package directory in PYTHONPATH**, and do it like this.

from mypackage.mymodule import as_int

You can also do this. But this is not recommanded for beginners.
You just frob the PYTHONPATH in code first with this...

```
import sys
import os

PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))

from mypackage.mymodule import as_int
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error did not go away. Same syntax error but it now points at the period `.` between `helper_functions` and `utility`

Comment: Seems like we are getting progress :)

Comment: Try this : `from ..helper_functions import utility`

Comment: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: Last question before I accept this answer. how would I do `You'll need to include the directory containing your package directory in PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Alan: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

Absolute imports are recommended in Pep 8:

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on sys.path ):

As for the `PYTHONPATH`, setting it once per terminal session where you work on the project might be best for now. Once you continue on to use an IDE like pycharm, this will be managed for you automagically

Comment: Relative imports are not so discouraged anymore, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641#answer-16748366

Comment: This phrasing is not included in the [current revision of pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Instead it says this: _Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on sys.path ):_