# NameError name 'Views' is not defined

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from collection import *


#from collection.views import index,thing_detail,edit_thing

urlpatterns = [ 
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
        url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),name='about'),
        url(r'^contact/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'),name='contact'),
        url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.thing_detail' ,name='thing_detail'),
        url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', 'views.edit_thing',name='edit_thing'), 
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

After running the server there is an error "NameError: name 'views' is not defined"

Any help ??

Comment: you aren't importing your own views

Comment: For what specific `view` you've got `NameError`, and If may I suggest change `from collection import *` to `from collection import views` if `collection` is your `app` name

Comment: First Import your views explicitly. Also avoid using string in urls (`'views.edit_thing'`) as it would raise a Deprecation Warning and is not a good habit too. And lastly use the callable view itself `edit_thing` rather `views.edit_thing`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't importing your own views.

Try adding this to your `urls.py`:

```
from . import views
```

Or if you are importing them from a specific app, try replacing `.` with the app name

Comment: This will probably solve the problem, but relative imports are not a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module

Comment: With how urls work in Django, I feel like relative imports won't confuse anyone

Comment: `Python 2.1.2` pragmatic is better than dogmatic

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is the `import *`, realize that this will/can cause confusion for other Developers reading your scripts. Python has a [methodology](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that insists that `explicit is better than implicit`. Which in this senario means you should be explicit about what you are importing.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from collection import views as collection_views

urlpatterns = [ 
        # Function Based Views
        url(r'^$', collection_views.index, name='home'),
        url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', collection_views.thing_detail ,name='thing_detail'),
        url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', collection_views.edit_thing,name='edit_thing'), 
        # Class Based Views            
        url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),name='about'),
        url(r'^contact/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'),name='contact'),
        # Admin
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Here instead of importing everything from collection I'm importing just your views and assigning them to a variable. Then using that variable in the URL definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to import your views by
specifying its location and the methods inside the view to be imported on your urls.py.

```
from . collection import *
```

(line above means from current location find collection.py and import everything on it)

Happy coding!