# Absolute and relative import of Python modules: a matplotlib example

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module

Many questions have been asked regarding how to import Python modules, specifically on whether to use absolute or explicit relative import ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module) for example). 
The import style, as suggested by the Python Software Foundation, can be found [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). In short, it recommends absolute import.

I'm writing this question because I assume the guys who develop matplotlib know what they are doing.

Given this assumption and assuming I understand the major/obvious differences between these two kinds of import, I would be interested in understanding the tiny differences between them that influenced the matplotlib's developers to write something like this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation
from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
                         TransformedPath, Transform)
from .path import Path
```

This is the beginning of `artist.py`, contained inside the `matplotlib` module (i.e. `matplotlib.artist`). I'm looking at matplotlib-1.5.1.

I would like to focus the attention on modules `matplotlib.cbook`, `matplotlib.transforms`, and `matplotlib.path`. All three of them are pure Python modules (i.e. `module_name.py` files).

Why `from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation` has been chosen rather than `from .cbook import mplDeprecation` and why `from .path import Path` was preferred to `from matplotlib.path import Path`?

Perhaps there is no particular reason and these choices just reflect different styles of different developers; perhaps there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to remember about the matplotlib code base is that it is very old (have git history back to 2003 and have lost another few years), large (>93k lines of python, 17k lines of c++), and has over 450 contributors.

Having a look at git-blame (off of the 2.x branch but the imports are pretty stable) shows:

```
08:29 $ git blame matplotlib/artist.py | head -n 18


5fca7e31 (Thomas A Caswell         2013-09-25 11:36:00 -0500    1) from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
5fca7e31 (Thomas A Caswell         2013-09-25 11:36:00 -0500    2)                         unicode_literals)
f4adec7b (Michael Droettboom       2013-08-14 10:18:10 -0400    3) 
07e22753 (Matthew Brett            2016-06-06 12:08:35 -0700    4) import six
0ea5fff3 (Thomas A Caswell         2015-12-01 14:40:34 -0500    5) from collections import OrderedDict
f4adec7b (Michael Droettboom       2013-08-14 10:18:10 -0400    6) 
453e0ece (Nelle Varoquaux          2012-08-27 23:16:43 +0200    7) import re
453e0ece (Nelle Varoquaux          2012-08-27 23:16:43 +0200    8) import warnings
731f6c86 (Michael Droettboom       2013-09-27 09:59:48 -0400    9) import inspect
e1d30c85 (Jens Hedegaard Nielsen   2015-08-18 19:52:48 +0100   10) import numpy as np
b44e8f20 (John Hunter              2008-12-08 23:28:55 +0000   11) import matplotlib
99b89a87 (John Hunter              2008-06-03 20:28:14 +0000   12) import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
c137a718 (Thomas A Caswell         2014-11-23 00:37:28 -0500   13) from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation
527b7d9a (Michael Droettboom       2010-06-11 18:17:52 +0000   14) from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
b2408c33 (Cimarron Mittelsteadt    2014-09-12 15:58:25 -0700   15) from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
b2408c33 (Cimarron Mittelsteadt    2014-09-12 15:58:25 -0700   16)                          TransformedPath, Transform)
f4adec7b (Michael Droettboom       2013-08-14 10:18:10 -0400   17) from .path import Path
f2a0c7ae (John Hunter              2007-03-20 21:48:31 +0000   18)
```

You can see that these lines were last touched by a number of people (apparently including me) over a range of years.

I would not read too much into this difference, but if you want to dive deeper try looking at the commit messages on those changes.

Comment: Ok, I suppose it's only due different developers' tastes. Perhaps you can tell us about yours then: why did you choose `from matplotlib.cbook ...` rather than `from .cbook ...` ?

Comment: @Gioker I honestly do not remember.  As you point out pep8 suggest absolute imports and it is more explicit.