# Lemmatize string according to pos nlp

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatize a string according to the part of speech but at the final stage, i'm getting an error. My code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
text = word_tokenize('People who help the blinging lights are the way of the future and are heading properly to their goals')
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):

    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return ''

for word in tagged: print(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word,pos='v'), end=" ")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-afb22c78f770> in <module>()
----> 1 for word in tagged: print(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word,pos='v'), end=" ")

E:\Miniconda3\envs\uol1\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py in lemmatize(self, word, pos)
     38 
     39     def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
---> 40         lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
     41         return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
     42 

E:\Miniconda3\envs\uol1\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in _morphy(self, form, pos)
   1710 
   1711         # 1. Apply rules once to the input to get y1, y2, y3, etc.
-> 1712         forms = apply_rules([form])
   1713 
   1714         # 2. Return all that are in the database (and check the original too)

E:\Miniconda3\envs\uol1\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in apply_rules(forms)
   1690         def apply_rules(forms):
   1691             return [form[:-len(old)] + new
-> 1692                     for form in forms
   1693                     for old, new in substitutions
   1694                     if form.endswith(old)]

E:\Miniconda3\envs\uol1\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1692                     for form in forms
   1693                     for old, new in substitutions
-> 1694                     if form.endswith(old)]
   1695 
   1696         def filter_forms(forms):
```

I want to be able to lemmatize that string based on each word's part of speech all at once. Please help.

Comment: I don't quite understand your approach: you want to lemmatize words, after checking for their POS to make sure you get the right lemma, is that it? If so, can you give an expected input & output? Also, what is the point of `get_wordnet_pos()` - I don't see it used anywhere?

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try not to mix top-level, absolute and relative imports like these:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
```

This would be better:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
```

(See [Absolute vs. explicit relative import of Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module))

The error you're getting is most probably because you are feeding in the outputs of `pos_tag` as the input to the `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()`, i.e. :

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> sent = 'People who help the blinging lights are the way of the future and are heading properly to their goals'.split()

>>> pos_tag(sent)
[('People', 'NNS'), ('who', 'WP'), ('help', 'VBP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('blinging', 'NN'), ('lights', 'NNS'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('way', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('future', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('heading', 'VBG'), ('properly', 'RB'), ('to', 'TO'), ('their', 'PRP$'), ('goals', 'NNS')]
>>> pos_tag(sent)[0]
('People', 'NNS')

>>> first_word = pos_tag(sent)[0]
>>> wnl.lemmatize(first_word)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py", line 40, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1712, in _morphy
    forms = apply_rules([form])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1694, in apply_rules
    if form.endswith(old)]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

The input to `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()` should be `str` not a tuple, so if you do:

```
>>> tagged_sent = pos_tag(sent)

>>> def penn2morphy(penntag, returnNone=False):
...     morphy_tag = {'NN':wn.NOUN, 'JJ':wn.ADJ,
...                   'VB':wn.VERB, 'RB':wn.ADV}
...     try:
...         return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
...     except:
...         return None if returnNone else ''
... 

>>> for word, tag in tagged_sent:
...     wntag = penn2morphy(tag)
...     if wntag:
...         print wnl.lemmatize(word, pos=wntag)
...     else:
...         print word
... 
People
who
help
the
blinging
light
be
the
way
of
the
future
and
be
head
properly
to
their
goal
```

---

Or if you like an easy way out:

```
pip install pywsd
```

Then:

```
>>> from pywsd.utils import lemmatize, lemmatize_sentence
>>> sent = 'People who help the blinging lights are the way of the future and are heading properly to their goals'
>>> lemmatize_sentence(sent)
['people', 'who', 'help', 'the', u'bling', u'light', u'be', 'the', 'way', 'of', 'the', 'future', 'and', u'be', u'head', 'properly', 'to', 'their', u'goal']
```