# Unable to find module/folder despite being in the same directory

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am attempting to run a script which calls another python file (copied along with its entire github repo),  but I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError:`
This is despite putting the files into the correct directories.

How I run it

1. Activate my python3.9 virtual environment
2. `(newpy39) aevas@aevas-Precision-7560:~/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12$ python3 dashboard.py` 
   where aevas is my username, and ~/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12 is the folder

No additional arguments required to run it.

Imports for dashboard.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack')

# Qt imports
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

import argparse
import configparser
import platform
import shutil
import time
import cv2
import torch
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn


from yolov5.utils.downloads import attempt_download
from yolov5.models.experimental import attempt_load
from yolov5.models.common import DetectMultiBackend
from yolov5.utils.datasets import LoadImages, LoadStreams
from yolov5.utils.general import LOGGER, check_img_size, non_max_suppression, scale_coords, check_imshow, xyxy2xywh
from yolov5.utils.torch_utils import select_device, time_sync
from yolov5.utils.plots import Annotator, colors
from deep_sort_pytorch.utils.parser import get_config
from deep_sort_pytorch.deep_sort import DeepSort
```

Part 1: Models not found, despite models being the parent folder.

```
python3 dashboard.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/dashboard.py", line 25, in <module>
    from trackerThread import trackerDeepSORT
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/trackerThread.py", line 15, in <module>
    from yolov5.models.experimental import attempt_load
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/targetTrack/yolov5/models/experimental.py", line 14, in <module>
    from models.common import Conv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Part 2: After changing import models.common to import common, it turns out even common cannot be found despite being in the same folder !

```
python3 dashboard.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/dashboard.py", line 25, in <module>
    from trackerThread import trackerDeepSORT
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/trackerThread.py", line 15, in <module>
    from yolov5.models.experimental import attempt_load
  File "/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/targetTrack/yolov5/models/experimental.py", line 14, in <module>
    from common import Conv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

This is how the files are like in the folder models
[image]

and this is how the import portion of experimental.py looks like

```
# YOLOv5  by Ultralytics, GPL-3.0 license
"""
Experimental modules
"""
import math

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


from common import Conv
from utils.downloads import attempt_download
```

I have consulted the following links, but to no avail:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c
2. [Python can't find module in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722212/python-cant-find-module-in-the-same-folder)
3. [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020963/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-models)
4. https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/353

I understand that I can change it to `import .common` and then the module can be successfully imported. However, the next line `import utils` causes a similar error. `utils` is on the same level as `models`. Which means there is going to be a cascade of `moduleNotFoundError` errors at this rate. I also understand using the `folder ()`method is inadvisable, hence I did not continue with it.

As I had mentioned that I had copied the entire cloned github repo over, when executed standalone, the github repo works perfectly fine. There are no differences between the `experimental.py`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you also provide the exact way you run the script ? What command are you running, from inside which directory do you run it ? Because it determines how Python will do its imports.

Comment: @Lenormju hello i have added a description of how i run it. Hope it clarifies what you need !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `models` module lives in the `/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/targetTrack/yolov5` folder, but when you run dashboard.py from `/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/`, the Python interpreter does not look inside the `/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/targetTrack/yolov5` folder to find modules; it only looks as far as files/folders in `/home/aevas/Desktop/Dashboard_2021_12/`.

The usual way to fix this would be by installing yolov5 as a package, but it does not appear that yolov5 contains the code necessary to be installed in such a way. To work around this, you need to let Python know that it needs to look inside the yolov5 folder to find the module.

The quick-and-dirty way of doing this is to [add the folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html).

A slightly less quick-and-dirty, but still pretty ugly way of doing it is by dynamically adding the yolov5 folder to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) before you try and import the `models` module. You would do this by adding something like the following to the top of dashboard.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__, "..", "targetTrack", "yolov5").resolve()))
```

Comment: Hey there. I actually tried using "sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack')" and it gave me the same problem. Sorry i missed that in the main question

Comment: sys.path needs an absolute path to the folder; just adding a relative path like "targetTrack" won't work. Also, why "targetTrack" and not "yolov5"?

Comment: the yolov5 folder is inside targetTrack. In the end i just used sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack') and sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack/yolov5')

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that the targetTrack folder was there. I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Also, it appears that I was wrong about sys.path needing absolute paths. I tested it, and relative paths also work, at least on Python 3.9.

Comment: You don't need to add `sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack')`, by the way. The import will work with only `sys.path.insert(1, 'targetTrack/yolov5')`.

Comment: Hey yes indeed it does work. But i find it very strange why does every folder needs its own sys.path.insert. It seems like a cascade of modulenotfound errors.

Comment: The usual way to avoid having lots of sys.path.insert calls is to install the code as a package. The Python packaging system deals with the import paths for you. If yolov5 was able to be installed as a package, then Pip would copy the `models` folder to a folder already present in sys.path, so that Python would detect it automatically.

The real fix here is to make yolov5 installable as a package. It might be worthwhile to raise this as an issue on the yolov5 GitHub page so that other people can solve this problem the easy way in the future.

Comment: Ok i understand now. I tried the quick and dirty method of adding the path to the pythonpath and it does work. A funny thing is, I moved the files over to another folder, renamed the main folder, and it worked. Everything started falling in place again and I have no idea why.