# Python nested subpackage doesn't import when running tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder structure like this:

```
api
-- test
    -- test_api.py
    -- __init__.py
-- api
    -- api.py
    -- __init__.py
    -- sub
        -- sub.py
        -- __init__.py
```

`sub.py`:

```
Base = 'base'
```

`api.py`:

```
from sub.sub import Base
```

def stuff_to_test():
    pass

`test_api.py`:

```
from api.api import stuff_to_test

def test_stuff_to_test():
    stuff_to_test()
```

I am in directory `api`.
I run `pytest`:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_api.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module '/<somepath>/api/tests/test_api.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_api.py:1: in <module>
    from ..api.api import stuff_to_test
api/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from . import api
api/api.py:1: in <module>
    from sub.sub import Base
E   ImportError: No module named 'sub'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.08 seconds ============================
```

Same happens if I run the `python` interpreter and import stuff from `test_api.py`:

```
>>> from tests.test_api import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<somepath>/api/tests/test_api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from api.api import stuff_to_test
  File "/<somepath>/api/api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/<somepath>/api/api/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sub.sub import Base
ImportError: No module named 'sub'
```

My first idea was to make the import in `api.py` relative:

```
from .sub.sub import Base
```

This way tests run fine. 
But if I run `python api/api.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sub.sub import Base
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

How can I have it so tests run and application runs?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by adding the following to `test.__init__.py`

```
project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
api_path= os.path.join(project_path, 'api')
sys.path.append(api_path)
```

Comment: For submodules, I would recommend using `from .sub.sub import Base` in api.py or at least an absolute `from api.sub.sub import Base`

Answer (score 0):

In python there are two ways to import a module, with a relative path or with an absolute path.
When you write `from sub.sub import Base` you are doing an absolute path import, for a relative path import write `from .sub.sub import Base`.

An absolute path import go look in the PYTHONPATH to find the starting point of your import, so you should write `from api.sub.sub import Base`.

For more information: [Absolute vs. explicit relative import of Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module)

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, sorry