# Python3 import issues when running directly vs pytests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-import

I have a project like

```
   .
   |-application
   |---foo.py
   |---bar.py
   |-tests
   |---test_foo.py
```

Contents are:

bar.py

```
def myfunc():
    return "hello from bar"
```

foo.py

```
from bar import myfunc


def do_work():
    return myfunc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(do_work())
```

test_bar.py

```
from application import foo


class TestFoo:
    def test_foo_do_work(self):
        assert foo.do_work() == "hello from bar"
```

Running `python application/foo.py` works great, but running `python -m pytest tests/` returns error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'`

In `foo.py` one way to fix this is to change the import line from `from bar import myfunc` to `from application.bar import myfunc`. This causes pytest to pass, but running `python application/foo.py` gives an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm using python 3.7 so I heard `__init__.py` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more googling, I have an answer. I created an `__init__.py` file inside of `tests` dir with the contents:

```
import os
import sys
project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
app_path = os.path.join(project_path, 'application')
sys.path.append(app_path)
```

From [Python nested subpackage doesn't import when running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810554/python-nested-subpackage-doesnt-import-when-running-tests)