# Imports in distributable python scripts

Tags: python, python-module, pypi

I have a python project pypypy with 2 files: `__main__.py` and `foo.py`.
In `__main__.py` I simply do import via `import foo`. It all works fine.

Now, I want to distribute it with pypi. After installing my module I'm execution it with `python -m pypypy`. When I do that, the import statement doesn't work anymore. However `import pypypy.foo` does the job.

Should I change all my imports before distribution or there is a better way?

Comment: What python version are you using? The import system differs between the two. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/8014793)

Comment: @hurlenko python 3.7

Comment: You should prefer imports relative to the package you distribute (like `import pypypy.foo`). The reason it works in your dev environment might be because of `PYTHONPATH` manipulation. For example Pycharm automatically sets _Add content and source roots to PYTHONPATH_. Also when you run python it automatically adds current working directory to PYTHONPATH

Comment: @hurlenko do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute imports is strongly suggested as they work consistently across different python versions. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748366/8014793). In your case you should prefer using `import pypypy.foo`.

The reason it works in your dev environment might be because of PYTHONPATH manipulation. For example Pycharm automatically sets *Add content and source roots to PYTHONPATH*. Also when you run python it automatically adds current working directory to PYTHONPATH.