# Python how to use absolute import

Tags: python, python-import

I have a file structure like this:

```
My_Package/
    __init__.py
    helper_fun.py
    sub_dir_1/
        __init__.py
        codes.py
```

I want to import functions from `helper_fun.py` while inside `codes.py`. I tried

```
from helper_fun import foo
from .helper_fun import foo
from ..helper_fun import foo
from My_package.helper_fun import foo
```

but none works. How should I use absolute import to always specify import directories from the top-level `My_Package`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs. explicit relative import of Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer but you can use :

```
 import os,sys,inspect
    currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
    sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

 import helper_fun
```

From : [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think that is still using relative import. I still want to know how to properly use absolute import.