# Why do I have to use a relative import in a package's __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-import

**Setup**

```
test/
    main.py
    pkg/
        a.py
        __init__.py
```

`main.py` contains:

```
import pkg    
pkg.a
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from . import a
```

`main.py` can be run without errors.

**Question**

Changing the content of `__init__.py` to

```
import a
```

gives the following error when running `main.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\test\pkg\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

Interestingly, `__init__.py` can be executed directly with `python __init__.py` without errors.

What's going on?

Comment: It's because your working directory is `test`, `import a` will search only in `test`, not includes the sub-directories.

Comment: Try `import pkg.a`, it should work if you run `main.py`

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Thanks... that is super confusing to me. Why can't `__init__.py` look for a module in the same folder regardless, like Python does by default in other cases?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen `import pkg.a` gives a `ModuleNotFoundError` too.

Comment: But the problem is when you change your working directory, say you are working in `pkg` or directory upper than `test`, it will error again. That's why relative path is preferable in these cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a python script, it's parent folder is added to `sys.path`

- run main.py: `sys.path[0] = '../test'`
- run **init**.py: `sys.path[0] = '../test/pkg'`

Your case: You try to "absolute-like" `import a` in `__init__.py` but the parent folder of `a.py` - which is `'../test/pkg'` - is not in the sys.path when you run `main.py`. This is why you get an error. However, your absolute import is incomplete as it should always start at the top level folder, e.g.

```
from test.pkg import a
```

Final answer to your question: **You don't have to use relative imports!**

See: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): *Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on sys.path).*

And keep in mind that relative imports don't work in a top-level-script when `__name__ = "__main__"`, but from imported modules only.

You can learn more about absolute and relative imports here:
[Absolute vs. explicit relative import of Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module)
https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Thanks. I understand the words you wrote but I don't understand them as an answer. :/

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I can never use the Python import system intuitively, despite reading what feels like every article on the internet about it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Pycharm? Then that's one of the confusion cause.

For example, let's say your directory looks like this

```
project1
    p1.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        pkg/
            a.py
            __init__.py
```

If you run (F10) the `main.py` your default working directory will be `project1/test`, which does not contain the `a.py` so `import a` will not find anything.

But if you run (F10) the `pkg/__init__.py` your working directory will be `project1/test/pkg` which has the `a.py`, and it works like what you tested.

So in these situation, if you use `from . import a` it will look for the directory that file is, `project1/test/pkg` in this case, which will always work regardless your working directory.