# What is the difference between local imports and package imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm currently going over a medium-sized code base. In some cases, other modules are imported with a relative path:

```
from .api.auth import jwt_load_user
```

and sometimes absolutely

```
from app.api.auth import jwt_load_user
```

Is there any difference? Is it just personal taste which style to choose?

Comment: There is some good answers to Absolute vs relative  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209641/7942856). Pep-8 also touches on this, suggesting absolute imports are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it's just a matter of personal taste and codebase style (unless there's some forbidden, evil `sys.path`/loader meta magic in use).