# what went wrong with my get and set properties?

Tags: python

Please I need help. I code with PyCharm and it keeps showing me unresolved reference 'model'.  Parameter 'model' value is not used and getter signature should be (self). Please how do I get around this.

```
class ProductObject:
    def __init__(self, product, brand, car, model, year):
        self.product = product
        self.brand = brand
        self.car = car
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def set_product(self, product):
        self.product = product.capitalize()

    def get_product(self):
        return self.product
    product = property(get_product, set_product)

    def set_brand(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand.title()

    def get_brand(self):
        return self.brand
    brand = property(get_brand, set_brand)

    def set_car(self, car):
        self.car = car.title()

    def get_car(self):
        return self.car
    car = property(get_car, set_car)

    def set_model(self):
        self.model = model.title()

    def get_model(self, model):
        return self.model
    model = property(get_model, set_model)

    def set_year(self):
        self.year = year.int()

    def get_year(self, year):
        return self.year
    year = property(get_year, set_year)
```

Comment: `getter` only expects `self` and setter should expect another argument apart from `self`. Now look at your `get_model` and `set_model` _carefully_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change parameters of methods. Get method needs only **self** and set method need **self** and **model** as parameter.

```
def set_model(self, model):
    self.model = model.title()

def get_model(self):
    return self.model
```

**EDIT**
Inheriting from your class:

```
class YourSubclass(ProductObject):
    #code of your subclass which inherit from ProductObject class
```

Module:
if you want create module you should check this [Module structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842616/organizing-python-classes-in-modules-and-or-packages)
Is it nothing more than classes with init.py file. You can then import classes with normal import statements. Here is another link with info about init.py file: [Init.py structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files)

Comment: Lastly please, am using pycharm and would want to create another subclass that would inherit from this one and how can I make my class importable as a module???

Comment: OK, no problems. I got you